# Картинка в php странице

Tags: php

Скажите, какой код надо использовать, чтобы на страничке отображалась картина от радикала?

```
[URL=http://www.radikal.ru][IMG]http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1110/c8/5ffe5c381e57.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бррр) 

`<img src="http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1110/c8/5ffe5c381e57.jpg" border=0>`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.)

Comment: Реально помогло? ..